# Prove that there exist $i \neq j$ with $ia_i \equiv ja_j$ mod $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and assume that $a_i \equiv i \pmod p$ for $ 1 \leq i \leq p-1$.

Prove that there exist $i \neq j$ with $ia_i \equiv ja_j \pmod p$.

This is one of my textbook problem but I could not figure out how to solve it.

Comment: $1a_1\equiv(p-1)a_{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$ for every $p\in\mathbb{N}$, and not only for every odd prime $p$. So either the answer to your question is obvious - choose $i=1$ and $j=p-1$, or some restriction is missing in it.

Comment: why $1a_1 \equiv (p-1)a_{p-1} \equiv 1$?

Comment: $1a_1\equiv1\pmod{p}$ is obvious, right?

Comment: $(p-1)a_{p-1}\equiv(p-1)(p-1)\equiv{p^2-2p+1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$, do you understand that?

Comment: It is implied from the fact that $({x}\cdot{y})\bmod{n}=(({x}\bmod{n})\cdot({y}\bmod{n}))\bmod{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $a_i \equiv i \mod p$ means that $ia_i \equiv i^2 \mod p$. So you want to find $i \neq j$ such that $i^2-j^2$ is divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, assume $1\le i<j\le p-1$. Now $1\le j-i\le p-1$.

We need to show one such $j$ exists which also satisfies $ia_i-ja_j\equiv 0(\mod p)\iff i^2-j^2\equiv 0(\mod p)$.

Note $(i-j)$ cannot be equivalent to $0(\mod p)$ **(why?)**.

So it all boils down to showing that a $j: 1\le j\le p-1$ exists such that $i+j\equiv 0(\mod p)$